# Is there another way to add a prop and return object within .map()

Tags: javascript, promise, bluebird

This is kind of nice, but it's a little confusing because I have to open up the promise and return the item.

```
Promise.map(assets, function(asset){
  asset.download_path = path.join(downloadDir, asset.name)
  return existsAsync(asset.download_path).then(function(exists){
    asset.exists = exists
    return asset;
  })
}).map(function(asset){
  if(asset.exists) return asset
  return downloadStream(asset.browser_download_url, asset.download_path).then(function(download){
    return asset
  })
})
```

Comment: What's your question? Does you code not work? What are you trying to do?

Comment: @PeterOlson I was more-or-less looking for a better way to do what I did above / confirmation that it is the correct way. Should have posted on code review.

Comment: Does it work? I can't see anything wrong with it. You could probably add the check `if(asset.exists)` to your `existsAsync` callback. Then just return `downloadStream` if `exists` is false

Comment: It works @SimpleJ that would return asset if it's `cached` and `downloadStream` returns `null` wouldn't be good.

Comment: I didn't mean just `downloadStream`. I'll just post what I meant as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make it look nicer, but in general it's fine:

```
return Promise.map(assets, function(asset){
  return existsAsync(path.join(downloadDir, asset.name));
}).map(function(ex, i){ 
    if(ex) return assets[i];
    return downloadStream(assets[i].downloadUrl, assets[i].downloadPath).return(assets[i]);
});
```

Or, with ex6 syntax:

```
import map from Promise

let exists = map(assets, a => existsAsync(path.join(downloadDir, a.name));
let download = a => downloadStream(a.downloadUrl, a.downloadPath).return(a);
return map(exists, (ex, i) => ex ? assets[i] : download(asset));
```

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to reduce your code down to a single map.

```
Promise.map(assets, function(asset){
  asset.download_path = path.join(downloadDir, asset.name)
  return existsAsync(asset.download_path).then(function(exists){
    asset.exists = exists
    if(exists){
      return asset;
    }
    return downloadStream(asset.browser_download_url, asset.download_path).then(function(download){
      return asset
    })
  })
});
```

Comment: You just replaced a "map" with nesting one level. How is that better?

Comment: It's not *better*. It's just simpler. I don't think I can improve his code without knowing more about the overall application.